# JSON POST Request - JSON data, How to do a post request with data in JSON format

Tags: php, javascript, json, post, httprequest

I want to post following data :

```
{
  "contactsync":
      { "rev":4,
        "contacts":[
                   { "fields": [
                                {
                                   "value":
                                      {
                                        "givenName":"dfgheeej",
                                        "familyName":"ffftestfff"
                                      },
                                   "type":"name",
                                   "flags":[],
                                   "op":"add"
                                },
                                {
                                   "value":"fffffff",
                                   "type":"nickname",
                                   "flags":[],
                                    "op":"add"
                                },
                                {
                                   "value":"fffff@fffff.com",
                                   "type":"email",
                                   "flags":[],
                                   "op":"add"
                                }
                            ],
                     "categories":[],
                     "op":"add"
                   }
       }
}
```

to a url. ( like : site.com/anything/add?format=json&wssid=t4764.444&wssid=some_value&windowid=&r=776566756 )

How do i post above data to a url through possibly javascript ? ( i want to create a html file for it containing script to do it. )

This all will not happen on same server, i want to post data from other server to other one.

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad : i tried XMLHTTPREQUEST pattern to do it and normal form submission method .. but that didn't work!

Comment: I played around with json between php and javascript but then the other way around. I think it can be a bity picky. Anyway, have you tried putting double quotation marks around the entire Json structure and escaping the other double quatation marks, and then in php decode the json again?

Comment: Modern browsers implement [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), which allows you to get a string representation of you object, but you I'm not sure that using such method is the best solution, from architectural point of view.

Comment: @DanielvanDommele : No i didn't had tried that.Can you post a example demonstrating how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax if you script will be on the same server, the server support CORS or the server support JSONP. Using jQuery it will be:

```
var data = {"contactsync":{"rev":4,"contacts":[{"fields":[{"value":{"givenName":"dfgheeej","familyName":"ffftestfff"},"type":"name","flags":[],"op":"add"},{"value":"fffffff","type":"nickname","flags":[],"op":"add"},{"value":"fffff@fffff.com","type":"email","flags":[],"op":"add"}],"categories":[],"op":"add"}]}};
var url = 'site.com/anything/addformat=json&wssid=t4764.444&wssid=some_value&windowid=&r=776566756';

$.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), function(response) {

});
```

if you can't use ajax you will need to create a proxy in php (just pass the json to the remote address and print response) like:

```
function post($url, $data) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

function get_raw_post_data() {
    if (isset($GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'])) {
        return $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];
    } else {
        return file_get_contents('php://input');
    }
}

$url = "site.com/anything/addformat=json&wssid=t4764.444&wssid=some_value&windowid=&r=776566756";

echo post($url, get_raw_post_data());
```

then insidead of url of remote site you use your script on the same server.

Comment: I want to post data on other remote server ( not same server ).

Comment: @Lady then use this php proxy I've written.